# Appsharing session disconnected due to RDP stack closed the connection

Tags: rdp, lync-2013

I am working on Appsharing in Lync-2013. My ICE-Check gets completed successfully and I get the ACK for re-invite response but after about 35-40 seconds, connection get terminated receiving a BYE message indicating the reason "Appsharing session disconnected due to RDP stack closed the connection". Am I missing something ?
Scenario: Lync client is the "sharer" and my Library is the "viewer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the RDP Stack through [`MS-RDPBCGR`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjABahUKEwiG8amMz9rHAhUCHo4KHXJLAws&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2FDOWNLOAD%2F9%2F5%2FE%2F95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C%2F%5BMS-RDPBCGR%5D.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEeKJXSQjfxd4BbbTyRHVuzvTPEmQ&sig2=me23sz36yyXOaX_arLUaRA) protocol to start a successful application share.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same problem between Lync Client:
Both Windows 8.1 with Lync 2013 Client 15.0.4701.1 But still one of us can share desktop to another. If we try to share desktop vice versa, It's giving that error in UccApi log and SQL Monitoring Database.

> Appsharing session disconnected due to RDP stack closed the connection

We opened a case with Microsoft.
They told:"Please try Installing latest update of Intel Display Adapter Driver of the presenter and attendee. You can find latest update on Intel website"
I said: "What if I'm using Windows Generic Driver Desktop sharing should be working"
They told: "Most of Customers having this issue because of Display Adapter is not up to date."
That Solution fixed few cases of our desktop clients, but still most of them with updated driver living with desktop sharing issue

I'm not convinced by their answer. But I'm just sharing if it helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

if it is citrix server Edgesight may cause this issue, Disable ES service and try, if it works add lync.exe in Process Exclusion